# 英語が残っている: 「クローズ」ダイアログのオフトピックまわりの文言

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

## 最初に理由を選択する画面

[image: 理由を選択する画面]

## オフトピックな理由を選択する画面

[image: オフトピックな理由を選択する画面]

## 「移行」を選択した時の画面

[image: メタの説明]

Answer (score 1):

> This question does not appear to be about スタック・オーバーフロー, within the scope defined in the ヘルプ センター.

---

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

---

> Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

---

> discussion, support, and feature requests for this site

---

```
この項目は、この質問に関連した書きかけの項目です。この項目を加筆・訂正などしてくださる協力者を求めています
```

Comment: この翻訳は別の方法で登録するため、メインとメタも含めてリストアップして、全体で同時に更新します。後日提供します。